# Error in plugin 'gulp-notify': No reporter specified

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sails.js, bower, gulp

I am trying to build a Sails.js and AngularJS app following this tutorial:

http://thoughtsmarkeddown.com/thoughts/javascript/setting-up-a-sails-js-with-angular-js-app-part-1/

I have setup my Sails App and angular App. Ater setting up the gulp file, which can be found here:

http://thoughtsmarkeddown.com/assets/Uploads/gulpfile.js

I ran the command `gulp` from my root folder and got the following error:

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
[gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify': No reporter specified.
```

I have no idea how to debug this. This is my first AngularJS app. Was just trying to use it with Sails for eaiser and faster development. If I am doing it the wrong way, can you suggest me some place else I should read about how to make a AngularJS + Sails.js app.

Following is the full stack trace:

```
[11:22:30] Using gulpfile ~/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/gulpfile.js
[11:22:30] Starting 'sass'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'sass' after 7.93 ms
[11:22:30] Starting 'sailsbasejs'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'sailsbasejs' after 3.04 ms
[11:22:30] Starting 'angularappjs'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'angularappjs' after 1.26 ms
[11:22:30] Starting 'bowerjs'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'bowerjs' after 5.78 ms
[11:22:30] Starting 'angularviews'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'angularviews' after 446 μs
[11:22:30] Starting 'watch'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'watch' after 216 ms
[11:22:30] Starting 'default'...
[11:22:30] Finished 'default' after 5.71 μs

stream.js:94
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
[gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-notify': No reporter specified.
    at report (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-                 notify/index.js:70:34)
    at Transform.notify [as _transform] (/home/sambhav/Prophesee     Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-notify/index.js:19:5)
    at Transform._read (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at Transform._write (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
    at doWrite (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:238:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:228:5)
    at Transform.Writable.write (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp-notify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:195:11)
    at Stream.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at queueData (/home/sambhav/Prophesee Media/PropheseeDashboard/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/map-stream/index.js:43:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of `gulp-notify` you are using? We had a similar issue on a CI-system on a linux machine (see this [issue](https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify/issues/11)). To solve this we've updated `gulp-notify` to the actual version 1.3.1.

To update your dev-dependencies you must remove the actual version first and install it again. It's a known bug from `npm` that you cannot use `npm update` on dev-dependencies. So what do I do?

```
# remove
npm rm --save-dev gulp-notify
# install again
npm install --save-dev gulp-notify
```

May it's helpful for you.

Ciao
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue:
https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate/issues/32

#### solution:

update gulp to 3.5.6

```
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.5.6",
  }
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't solve the issue. I have tested v 3.5.2, 3.5.6 and 3.8.0.
Updated both global as well cli versions

Answer (score 0):

Try below command :

`npm install --save gulp-notify`  //use **save** this will save the dependencies in package.json

Hope this will work!!